# wait_until behavior for time_point::max

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

On an embedded platform I ran into the issue that when waiting on a condition until `time_point<clock>::max()`, the program enters a busy loop completely using a CPU.

The program I am running is:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::mutex mutex;
  std::condition_variable condition;

  using namespace std::chrono;
  using clock = steady_clock;
  for (;;) {
    auto forever = time_point<clock>::max();
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

    std::cout << "Now waiting" << std::endl;
    condition.wait_until(lock, forever);
    std::cout << "Now waking up" << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I was quite sure this is a bug, and running this on my host's compiler (g++ 4.7) the application behaved as I expected (blocking forever). When writing a bug report I wanted to attach an ideone sample demonstrating the issue, but ideone also runs into a busy loop:

http://ideone.com/XPy0Wn

Now I am unsure who is correct here. Is there a standard definition of how wait_until on a condition should behave when the second argument is `time_point<clock>::max()`?

Comment: What is your exact problem? Application waking up spontaneously or that it uses all CPU? Do other kind of wait exgibit this behavior (do a `wait_until` time point a minute in the future and check). What is return value of `wait_until`? Why didn't you used predicate version to protect from spurious wakeups?

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot My main issue here is the CPU usage. Other kinds of wait do not lead to this issue. I am aware of spurious wakeups, and I am not using the predicate version because in the code that this sample originates from the wait is in a loop checking the condition anyway. From my understanding that should be equivalent to the predicate version. This sample is just supposed to illustrate the issue.

Comment: One idea is that clock adjustement causes time point to overflow and cause all sort of problems.

Comment: At least, try to check the reason for which the thread is waken up. That is, check if the return value of `wait_until` is `std::cv_status::timeout` or `std::cv_status::no_timeout`. This will give you a clue of what's happening there.

Comment: @skypjack Interesting. Ideone is reporting timeout, my embedded platform is reporting no_timeout. Both are consistent in their return values.

Comment: @nijansen So, spurious wake up. It happens and it's accepted by the standard. That's all. Should I turn my comments in an answer?

Comment: @skypjack Feel free to. I'll still try my luck  with a bug report since it does not happen when the time point is less far in the future, and hundreds of spurious wakeups per millisecond still seem strange to me.

Answer (score 5):

You likely observe a (silly) conversion of steady clock to system clock time:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono;

time_t silly_steady_clock_to_time_t( steady_clock::time_point t )
{
    return system_clock::to_time_t(system_clock::now()
         + (t - steady_clock::now()));
}

int main() {
      auto system_time = system_clock::to_time_t(system_clock::now());
      auto forever = time_point<steady_clock>::max();
      auto forever_time = silly_steady_clock_to_time_t(forever);
      std::cout << ctime(&forever_time) << '\n';
      std::cout << ctime(&system_time) << '\n';
      return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Fri Jun 16 11:40:31 1724
Tue Sep 27 15:44:54 2016
```

Note: the steady forever_time is in the past.

A change of `clock` to `using clock = system_clock;` will fix the issue.

Comment: Likely related to this 5 year old GCC bug: http://gcc-bugs.gcc.gnu.narkive.com/LBRgUQhD/bug-c-58931-new-condition-variable-wait-until-overflowed-by-large-time-point-steady-clock

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, if you want to try to track it down, you should check the return type of the call to `wait_until`.
It can be either `std::cv_status::timeout` or `std::cv_status::no_timeout`.
By doing that, you'll be able to understand what's going on there.

As mentioned in the standard, the return type adheres to the following rules:

> `cv_status::timeout` if the absolute timeout specified by `abs_time` expired, otherwise `cv_status::no_timeout`.

Moreover:

> The function will unblock when signaled by a call to `notify_one()`, a call to `notify_all()`, expiration of the absolute timeout specified by `abs_time`, or spuriously.

Likely the last one is your case and it's unlikely a bug.
You should rather look for the reasons that give place to those spurious wakeups.